# why cant subclass objects hold super class constructor

Tags: java, superclass

Can anybody explain me what is the reason for a sub class object is incapable of holding a super class constructor?

```
class Alpha 
{
   String getType1() 
   {
      return "alpha";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha 
{
   String getType1() 
   {
      return "beta";
   }
   String acc()
   {
      return "acc"; 
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Alpha a1=new Beta();
   System.out.println(a1.getType1());
 }
```

Here the output is "beta"; but object a1 doesnt have the visibility to acc()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing surprising here:

```
System.out.println(a1.getType1());
```

You are calling a method that is defined in the super class; and overridden in the a subclass. You create an instance of the subclass; and the method that gets executed ... is the overridden version.

The fact that Beta contains **another** method which is **not at all** used in your example anyway doesn't come into play here at all. And even if `getType1()` would be calling `acc()` - that would still work. That is the **essence** of of [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)!

And just to be precise: **none** of the methods you have in your classes is a **[constructor](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html)**!

Comment: can u help me understand what is the functional and non functional requirements for junit please

Comment: That is a pretty broad subject. Can you give a bit more of context? The only thing to say without further information: A) the functional requirement of test cases ... is to **verify** the corresponding production code. B) non-functional requirements ... I would see those "properties" for example that make up "good" unit tests; as outlined [here](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the answer here we need to know that when we create beta() internally it will call all its super class default constructors hence the JVM knows that there is more than one existing class but when i declare and initialze like:

```
 Alpha a1=new Beta();
```

eventhough the JVM knows that beta class is existing but your restricting your access of a1 by saying it is of the type Alpha class hence it cannot access your subclass methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a object of child class making reference to its parent class as you did, you only have visible to those methods which belongs to the parent class. but if you want to call the child method using reference of parent class then you have to declare the body of the method in parent class which you have in child class. then it will be visible and this concept is called method overriding.

If you don't need to create the object of your super class then you can declare class as abstract and then you can simply put that method as abstract keyword shown as below.

```
abstract class Alpha 
{
   String getType1() 
   {
      return "alpha";
    }

   abstract String acc();
   
}

class Beta extends Alpha 
{
   String getType1() 
   {
      return "beta";
   }

   @Overriding
   String acc()
   {
      return "acc"; 
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Alpha a1=new Beta();
   System.out.println(a1.getType1());
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Child classes are privileged to access to default constructor of parent class until unless you have restricted it with private access modifier.

Your cases is an example of method overloading. Actual call to overloaded method is resolved at run time. Which method will be called, depends on the concrete object not type of object. Here your reference is of type Alpha but the object is of Type Beta. So method `getType1()` here will print beta which is correct behavior.

Comment: It is a lot less common to edit an answer than to edit a question, especially when the edit *changes the answer* significantly. The common practice is to write comments asking the author to correct their question, or assume that they do not know what they are talking about and downvoting.